# How could I use a tournament selection genetic algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I recently programmed a tournament selection genetic algorithm, but don't know what to use it for as it seems all solutions would be self-explanatory. I calculate the fitness of each individual based on a list

```
for i in range(num_attributes):
    weighted_values.append(random.uniform(-4,4))
```

and then I give each individual in the population a value:

```
for i in range(int((populationSize))):
        population_weights.append([random.uniform(-10, 10) for _ in range(num_attributes)])
```

I calculate the fitness by multiplying each individual's *n*th weight by the *n*th weight in the list of all the values. However, it would seem that if we know what the list of values are (say, 1, 3, -2); it would be a matter of seconds to see that the best solution would be an individual with values of (10, 10, and -10). What, then, is the purpose of the tournament selection?

Comment: When you are building a selection algorithm, usually there is a "mission" that you want to build a population (or individual) who is able to accomplish it. The "fitness function", AFAIK, is a function that tests how well each individual is doing in that mission, so the evolution process depends on *what does it mean to do something well*. Maybe this approach of multiplying the weights is pointless.

Comment: Alright, that seems reasonable. Do you have any common 'missions' for these individuals? I asked Google about real-life tournament selection algorithm examples, but wasn't answered properly. Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused about what you mean with "tournament selection". For example, if there is a **jumping tournament** and the best individuals are those who can jump higher, you would get the genes (e.g.: a gene is strength in left food, another is strength in right foot, another is total weight, etc.) and put them all into some kind of equation (which is the fitness function, that checks how well the individuals accomplish the mission of jumping) that gives you a result which you can use to compare.

Comment: You will train your population for a specific reason. The genetic algorithm is frequently the same for most of applications, but the fitness function is application-specific. In the example above, a reasonable equation could be `( left_foot_strength + right_foot_strength ) / total_weight` and the goal of the training is to increase this value.

Comment: By 'tournament selection' I mean having a population of individuals, picking k random number of individuals from the population, and finding the best of them. The best individual in this 'tournament' would be added to the parent pool. As for your jumping suggestion, again, this leads back to the part I don't understand about genetic algorithms. It is clear that for the fitness function equation the best solution would be extremely high left and right foot strength and as small weight as possible. This can easily be computed, so there is no need for a GA, right? Aappreciate the help so far.

Comment: So it's all up to your definition of *best* (which is the result of the fitness function). The fitness function is a function that takes as input all the genes of  an individual and outputs a score that is used to rank him among the other individuals. It is up to you defining what will each of the genes mean and how to evaluate them building a good fitness function.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, well, I just designed the GA for fun and wanted to see if I could extend it to help me with some other projects that I am working on. However, I have very little in the way of knowledge on the topic of creating fitness functions in genetic algorithms. In the case of the equation for jumping you suggested above, to prevent having insanely high strengths and small weights, would there be some sort of 'punishment' involved? Where the higher the foot strength, the greater the energy cost or something like that? Or do you have any concrete workable equation examples for me? Thanks.

Comment: There isn't really a "punishment", but you can create this behaviour in the fitness function, for example, suppose if an individual jumps so high that he touches the ceiling, it breaks a rule, so you could use this boolean fact to make the fitness function return some low value. But the idea is just to let the population be tested, reproduce, mutate, etc. until it achieves the expected fitness score or until a certain number of iterations is complete. I think for more specific doubts, you'd better ask new questions.